# How to install OS in new Hard disk using my old CD key?

Tags: operating-systems

I bought Laptop with built in Window 7 Pro (with cd key) and CD Recovery, my problem is my Hard disk was crash and I need to replace it in a new one, That is why I bought a clean Hard disk, how can I install my Window 7 which have CD-key using Recovery disk?

Comment: Should be on Super User

Comment: If you know the key (check the COA sticker on the bottom of the laptop), just download a copy of Win7 from [here](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) and install afresh.

Answer (score 0):

Just boot to the CD and perform a "clean install" with the new key.

Comment: There is no Clean Install in my CD recovery, just Repair, Install Driver, Select Recovery selection.